# C++ program ignoring the first character after the first input

Tags: c++, input, cin

Here is the code in the main class where I am asking for input.

```
Class in(nameOfClass, numOfStudents);
for (int i = 0; i < numOfStudents; i++)
{
    cout << "\nEnter the name of student " << i + 1 << ": ";
    string studentName = "";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, studentName);
    cout << "\n ~ Enter the grades for " << studentName << endl;
    cout << " ~ (Use this format: 3 - 100 100 100)" << endl;
    cout << " ~ ";
    string gradeLine = "";
    getline(cin, gradeLine);
    Student stu = Student(studentName, gradeLine); in .addStudent(i, stu);
    cout << endl;
}
```

For the first run of the loop, the `studentName` reads in all the characters including spaces since I used `getline(cin, studentName);`. If I input `"Andrew"`, then `studentName` will read in `"Andrew"`.

However, for all further runs of the loops, if I input `"Andrew"` for the name of the student, the program stores `"ndrew"` into the `studentName` variable. I tried using `cin.ignore()`, `cin.clear()`, and `cin.sync()` in different places in the loop, but it stops the input and I need to enter a `'\n'` for it to to keep going and ask for the next student's information.

How do I clear the buffer after the loop is done so that my next run on the loop reads all the characters, but the loop does not pause and waits for the user to enter `'\n'`?

Comment: The only thing I see wrong in your input stream code so far is the `cin.ignore()` line. Everything else looks like it should work.

Comment: If I leave out the `cin.ignore()`, then the compiler skips the part where it reads in the student's name. It just prints out "Enter the name of student 1: 
~Enter the grades for"

Comment: Then you have a previous input which left residual whitespace in there. Replace the `cin.ignore()` with `cin >> ws`.

Comment: Yes, `cin >> ws;` worked. Thank you.

Comment: Great! BTW, `std::cin.ignore()` simply ignores a single character while `std::cin >> std::ws` clears whitespace until it finds a non-whitespace character. `std::cin.clear()` is not an input function, it simply clears all the error flags on the stream (by default). And lastly, `std::cin.sync()` is the equivalent of flushing an output stream buffer, only for input streams. Its behavior is highly implementation-defined so there's no reason to use it whatesoever.